# Why does it say "EOL while scanning string literal" when i run this email program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a python script to send email with a gmail account. I was using Python 3.7 but when I went to run the program it said `"EOL while scanning string literal"` in a message box. Can anyone fix this? Tell me if you find a way to fix it.

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

#Next, log in to the server
server.login("youremailusername", "password")

#Send the mail
msg = "
Hello!" # The /n separates the message from the headers
server.sendmail("you@gmail.com", "target@example.com", msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

EOL = End Of Line

This error tells you it encounters an 'End of Line' while scanning the string literal. A normal string is not expected to be multiple lines.

Use triple quotes to remedy this:

```
msg = """
Hello!"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
msg = ""
```

The error pops up only when there an unended string.